# Synapse LINK Load streaming DataFrame from Azure Cosmos DB container

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I am trying to use feed changes on synapse, I am using synapse link to connect to cosmos,

```
dfStream = spark.readStream\
    .format("cosmos.oltp")\
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "<enter linked service name>")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.container", "<enter container name>")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.changeFeed.readEnabled", "true")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.changeFeed.startFromTheBeginning", "true")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.changeFeed.checkpointLocation", "/localReadCheckpointFolder")\
    .option("spark.cosmos.changeFeed.queryName", "streamQuery")\
    .load()
```

But I'm getting the error below:

> Error : org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, DELETE, https://adlsgarage7.dfs.core.windows.net/adlsgarage7/localReadCheckpointFolder/streamQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You need the permission to access as a contributor the container of the Data Lake Account that has been connected to the workspace at the time of creation. You need **Blob Storage Contributor** ARM access to the account adlsgarage7 or at least the container adlsgarage7.

You should also make sure to write the name of the linked service you connect to and the container.